# What should be the type/value of a primary key that should be unlimited

Tags: database, database-design, types, primary-key

I am making a messaging system wherein both authenticated and unauthenticated users should be able to use. Each index of the message should be unique. I am thinking of using bigint but it has a limit of about 18446744073709551615 (unsigned) which would not be ideal for me if I want to keep a record of all the messages. Also, I am thinking of a timestamp but there is a possibility that more than one user will post a message at the same time. Hence, the created timestamp will collide with other timestamp.

Do you guys have an idea what should be done here?

Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: In order to handle an infinite number of messages in your database, you'd need an infinite number of hard drives.

Comment: With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) possible values.
If start at 1 and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ... is that **really** too limited for you??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously?  If 100 messages are posted every second, BigInt will give you sufficient ids for, by my rough calculation, 6 billion years.  By then you can probably archive a few messages and start the sequence over.

Comment: +1, and if Moore's law applies to int widths, I'm sure we'll have at least an int128 available by then.